In search of a specific mystery series/episode - several double-crosses and twists
I saw a mystery hour rerun in the days before DVR or interactive menus with episode titles (very long ago), and have been obsessed with finding it ever since.  I originally presented this question as an Alfred Hitchcock episode request (the storytelling fits his style), but given the available brain trust on this site I think I need expand the possible realm of shows now that the question remains unanswered.
The recurring theme of the plot is double-crosses, something along the lines of: a woman is planning to kill her husband and run away with her boyfriend, but he's planning to kill her and run away with the maid, who is planning to poison them all and steal a priceless family artifact, and so on.  I made most of this up because I can't remember the specific characters or twists, but the many double-crosses are definitely the pet theme of the episode.  I believe this episode was originally produced in the 50's or 60's, based on the black-and-white format and my vague recollections of furnishings, wardrobe, and general style.
Two details I do remember: 

a car driving over a bridge (which had been rigged to explode) on its approach to the house as two sinister onlookers watched from the window, and
the ending:


 A couple getting on a small airplane in place of the original ticket-holders (who are now dead).  The plane steward closes the airplane door saying to nobody specific that he was given some instructions to kill whoever shows up with the plane tickets if the original ticket holders should not arrive for the flight.

Does this ring a bell with anyone?
I do think it could be a Hitchcock television series episode, or after more research maybe Edgar Wallace.  I've seen some of his mysteries and the style fits well also.  I can confirm that it is not Edgar Wallace's "Ricochet."
